# Different model accuracy when rerunning preProcess(), predict() and train() in R (caret)

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, glm

The data below is just an example, it is operations on this , or any, data which I am confused about:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(3433)
data(AlzheimerDisease)
complete <- data.frame(diagnosis, predictors)
in_train <- createDataPartition(complete$diagnosis, p = 0.75)[[1]]
training <- complete[in_train,]
testing <- complete[-in_train,]
predIL <- grep("^IL", names(training))
smalltrain <- training[, c(1, predIL)]

fit_noPCA <- train(diagnosis ~ ., method = "glm", data = smalltrain)
pre_proc_obj <- preProcess(smalltrain[,-1], method = "pca", thresh = 0.8)
smalltrainsPCs <- predict(pre_proc_obj, smalltrain[,-1])
fit_PCA <- train(x = smalltrainsPCs, y = smalltrain$diagnosis, method = "glm")
fit_noPCA$results$Accuracy
fit_PCA$results$Accuracy
```

When running this code, I get a 0.689539 accuracy for `fit_noPCA` and 0.682951 accuracy for `fit_PCA`. But when I rerun the last portion of the code:

```
fit_noPCA <- train(diagnosis ~ ., method = "glm", data = smalltrain)
pre_proc_obj <- preProcess(smalltrain[,-1], method = "pca", thresh = 0.8)
smalltrainsPCs <- predict(pre_proc_obj, smalltrain[,-1])
fit_PCA <- train(x = smalltrainsPCs, y = smalltrain$diagnosis, method = "glm")
fit_noPCA$results$Accuracy
fit_PCA$results$Accuracy
```

Then each time I rerun these 6 lines I get different accuracy values. Why is this so? Is it because I am not resetting the seed? Even if, where is the inherent randomness of this process?

Comment: What are these values? Are they varying a lot or only in the last few decimal numbers?

Comment: They are values like 0.6688098 and 0.7012564, 0.6691034 and 0.7106764 or 0.6932403 and 0.687635 for `fit_noPCA` and `fit_PCA`, respectively. So I think they are varying quite a lot, and also it is not always that one fit is better than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the model is trained using bootstrap, you can see it here:

```
library(caret)
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)

> fit_noPCA
Generalized Linear Model 

251 samples
 12 predictor
  2 classes: 'Impaired', 'Control' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 251, 251, 251, 251, 251, 251, ... 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy   Kappa     
  0.6870006  0.04107016
```

So with every `train` , the bootstrapped samples will be different, to get back the same result, you can set the seed before running train:

```
set.seed(111)
fit_PCA <- train(x = smalltrainsPCs, y = smalltrain$diagnosis, method = "glm",trControl=trainControl(method="boot",number=100))
fit_PCA$results$Accuracy
[1] 0.6983512

set.seed(112)
fit_PCA <- train(x = smalltrainsPCs, y = smalltrain$diagnosis, method = "glm",trControl=trainControl(method="boot",number=100))
fit_PCA$results$Accuracy
[1] 0.6991537

set.seed(111)
fit_PCA <- train(x = smalltrainsPCs, y = smalltrain$diagnosis, method = "glm",trControl=trainControl(method="boot",number=100))
fit_PCA$results$Accuracy
[1] 0.6983512
```

Or use for example cv where you can define the folds using `index=` in `trainControl`

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense